# List equality using parser combinators

Tags: scala, parser-combinators

I've grabbed some Scala CSV parsing code from here:

[Use Scala parser combinator to parse CSV files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5063022/use-scala-parser-combinator-to-parse-csv-files)

And then I tried to write a basic test for it:

```
assertEquals(List(List()), CSV.parse(""))
```

And this fails, with message:

java.lang.AssertionError: expected: scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon but was: scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon

Any ideas?  The output from CSV.parse is an empty List[List[String]] but seems to have a different hashCode than List(Nil) or ListList[String] etc.  I can't seem to find any way to compose a list which is equal to the output of CSV.parse("").

**UPDATE:**

Here is the failure using REPL:

```
scala> assertEquals(List(Nil), CSV.parse("")) 
java.lang.AssertionError: expected: scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon<List(List())> but was: scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon<List(List())>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edited:** I tried the parser you supplied in the link:

```
scala> CSV.parse("")
res7: List[List[String]] = List(List(""))
```

So apparently, it doesn't return a List with an empty List, but a List with a List with the empty string. So your test should fail.

Comment: Good catch, thanks, thats it.  What confused me is that println(List(List("")) and println(List[List[String]](Nil)) have the same output, so in my println calls, and in the JUnit failures I seemed to be getting the same values on either side.

Comment: I don't (yet) understand how/why the REPL shows different output than toString.