# What are the implications of using def vs. val for constant values

Tags: function, scala, immutability, idioms

What are the implications of using `def` vs. `val` in Scala to define a constant, immutable value? I obviously can write the following:

```
val x = 3;
def y = 4;
var a = x + y; // 7
```

What's the difference between those two statements? Which one performs better / is the recommended way / more idiomatic? When would I use one over the other?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Assuming these are class-level declarations:

The compiler will make a `val` `final`, which can lead to better-optimised code by the VM.

A `def` won't store the value in the object instance, so will save memory, but requires the method to be evaluated each time.

For the best of both worlds, make a companion object and declare constants as `val`s there.

i.e. instead of

```
class Foo {
  val MyConstant = 42
}
```

this:

```
class Foo {}

object Foo {
  val MyConstant = 42
}
```

Comment: »Will save memory«? The value has to be stored _somewhere_, I don't see why one form would require more memory than the other …?

Comment: @knittl If you have a thousand instances, a field will be stored a thousand times. A method definition is only stored once.

Comment: Maybe also the `def` gets stored in permgen, while the val will get stored on the heap? I don't know where static members go.

Answer (score 1):

The `val` is evaluated once and stored in a field. The `def` is implemented as a method and is reevaluated each time, but does not use memory space to store the resulting value.